# Action url for a form

Tags: php, laravel

My routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'product'], function () {
    Route::get('{id}', 'ProductController@product')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
    Route::post('{id}/add', 'ProductController@addToCart')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
});
```

From the `product/{id}` page i wan't to do a POST to `product/{id]/add`

But what is the best way to get the form action url?

Now i have:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ Request::url() }}/add">
```

It works, but I don't like it... And there must be a beter way...

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('ProductController@addToCart') }}/add">
```

Given me an exception...

**Missing required parameters for [Route: ] [URI: product/{id}/add]. (View: .../resources/views/product/product.blade.php)**

Answer (score 1):

If you dislike that, you can use route naming:

```
Route::post('{id}/add', 'ProductController@addToCart')
    ->name('product.add')
    ->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

and then:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('product.add', $id) }}">
```

where `$id` is a id of a element to pass.

Comment: Does ```$id``` refer to the parameter?

Comment: I'm getting a ```Undefined variable: id```

Comment: Yes it refers the parameter you define in route as `{id}`

Comment: `Undefined variable: id` <- I'm give you only the example. You have to get `$id` by yourself in the view partial :)